# drop down list wise xml all attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, drop-down-menu

i have one xml file:-

```
<child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
    <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
        <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
            <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
        </child_10067>
    </child_10066>
    <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
</child_4>
```

i want to result some thing like this:-

Firlst Look:-

```
Activities
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Physical
```

after click on `Activities` drop down there child list:-

```
Activities
          Physicall
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Physical
```

if click on `Physicall`

```
Activities
          Physicall
                   Cricket
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Physical
```

something like tree type
look like drop down menu...

thanks...

Comment: there are lots of tutorials and other web resources as well as posts on this site how to parse xml with jQuery/javascript

Answer (score 1):

I made jquery version

```
var xml = [
'<child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">',
    '<child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">',
        '<child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">',
            '<child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>',
        '</child_10067>',
    '</child_10066>',
    '<child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>',
    '<child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>',
    '<child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>',
    '<child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>',
    '<child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>',
'</child_4>'
].join('');
```

and code is :

```
function makeHtml( $xml , $ul ){

     $xml.each( function(){

            var $node =  $(this) ;

            var $li = $('<li></li>').html( $node.attr('value') );

            $ul.append( $li ); 

            if ( $node.children().length > 0 ) {

                 $childUl = $('<ul></ul>').hide(); 

                 $ul.append( $childUl ); 

                 // toggle hide and show
                 $li.click( function(){

                        if( $(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
                            $(this).next().show();
                        } else {
                            $(this).next().hide();
                        }  
                 });

                 makeHtml( $node.children() , $childUl );
            }                        

    }); 
} 

makeHtml( $( xml ) , $('ul') );
```

and added in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PLH8D/3/

Comment: i am try to load xml using jquery something this type:-  `function load()
 {
          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
    async: false,
                url: "reg.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data){
    var xml = [data].join('');
    makeHtml( $( xml ) , $('ul') );
}
        });
 }
` but got the error `unrecognized expression: [object XMLDocument]`

Comment: @JackPhp `xml` varible should xml `string` , try console.log( data ), may be it not a xml string .. `[data].join('');` will work , if data is `Array`

Comment: @JackPhp try `success: function(data){ var xml = data ; makeHtml( $( xml ) , $('ul') ); }`

Comment: i have huge xml file but i want to just `<child_4>to</child_4>` element... ?

Comment: array concept is very misleading in this solution... xml doc received by AJAX is not an array. @rab only used it to be able to manipulate a javascript string for demo